# get top two (slice?) in field1 from explode and count in field2

Tags: php, explode, slice

```
myTable

field1    |   field2
------------------------
47       |    46,43,22,88,99,12
22       |    12,99
88       |    77
12       |    99,22,84,5
```

Using PHP am looking to pull from my db (Mysql 5.x) the  2 values from field1 that have the most values in field2. this is for Joomla/JomSocial if it matters but any reply is greatly appreciated.

```
The out put of the following query should be
Top Member ID = 47
Top Member ID = 12
```

I have tried this but nothing happend:

```
    $query  =   'SELECT * FROM myTable;

    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $row = $db->loadObjectList();        
    $counted = array_count_values($row[field2]);
    arsort($counted);
    $top_two = array_slice($counted, 0, 2);
    foreach ( $top_two as $data )
        {
            echo "Top Member ID = " . $data ."<BR />";
        }
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in straight SQL:

```
SELECT field1, field2, LENGTH(field2)-LENGTH(REPLACE(field2,',','')) AS num FROM myTABLE ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 2;
```

The 2 rows returned will be the ones you want.

Comment: Wow you guys are screamin' fast.... I thnk I love this forum. Going to plug it into my script now and try it out... thank you!

Comment: ctcherry, is the counting the number of elements in field2 or the string length?

Comment: Ahh... counting the commas.  Good idea.

Comment: @user1006292: it is counting the number of commas.  Take the length of the whole string (ex. `1,2,3,4 = 7`) then subtract off the length of the string when you replace commas with '' (ex. `1234 = 4')... so this will give you 3.  3 isn't the number of elements, but it is consistent, so ordering by will be fine.

Comment: @ctcherry Wow great way, i was really cracking my head open trying to find an anwser that would have been MUCH more complex :) Cheers

Comment: Yeah probably won't perform great on LARGE (millions or records) data sets, but likely more performant than doing it in PHP! :)